# Warnings when installing pip

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, python

I just installed `pip` and got a few warning messages. Should I be concerned? Is there a way to check that `pip` was installed properly?

Here's what I did:

```
[mchenja@mycomp ~]$ sudo easy_install pip
Password:

Searching for pip
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Best match: pip 7.0.3
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-7.0.3.tar.gz#md5=54cbf5ae000fb3af3367345f5d299d1c
Processing pip-7.0.3.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-yd6xox/pip-7.0.3/setup.cfg
Running pip-7.0.3/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-yd6xox/pip-7.0.3/egg-dist-tmp-YX6Zk1
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.coveragerc'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.mailmap'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.travis.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'pip/_vendor/Makefile'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'tox.ini'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'dev-requirements.txt'
no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'contrib'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tasks'
no previously-included directories found matching 'tests'
Adding pip 7.0.3 to easy-install.pth file
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip

[mchenja@mycomp ~]$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

[mchenja@otori ~]$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: Start installing stuff, see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will almost certainly be fine. Try `pip install pip` and it should tell you "Requirements already satisfied". You could also try `pip show pip` and it will tell you it is installed and requires no other packages.